# INNER JOIN retornando erro

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Estou tentando um INNER JOIN entre 3 tabelas mais retorna erro, não sei o que esta errado.
[image: imagens das 3 tabelas]
Query:

```
SELECT
    aa.arq_arqid,
    aa.arq_nome,
    aa.arq_nomecrip,
    aa.arq_datetime,
    u_usuarios_u_userid
    a_area_a_areaid
FROM arq_arquivos as aa
INNER JOIN u_usuarios as usr
ON u_usuarios_u_userid = usr.u_userid
INNER JOIN a_area as ar
ON a_area_a_areaid = ar.a_areaid
```

Comment: falta uma virgula depois de u_usuarios_u_userid

Comment: Realmente falta uma virgula, mas ainda da erro. #1054 - Unknown column 'u_usuarios_u_userid' in 'field list'

Comment: Nenhuma tabela tem a coluna u_usuarios_u_userid, apenas u_usuarios_u_useid, falta um R

Comment: @user1811893 problema resolvido, grato.